# what does the が mean here?

Tags: grammar

[image]

what does the が mean here? it definitely seems like its marking subject, but, does it connect the text thats under it? it doesnt make too much sense for me, to say to the other person
"a guy which i dont know what kind of person it is take as much as you want!" just doesnt make sense, whats the purpose of it there?

Comment: 好きなだけ持ってけ is a different sentence.